# Finding $\lim \frac{\sin{2x}}{\cosh(\cosh{x})}$ as $x$ goes to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{2x}}{\cosh(\cosh{x})}$

My thoughts: as $x$ goes to $0$ that $\sin(2x)$ is approximated by $2x$. So

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{2x}}{\cosh(\cosh{x})} =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{\cosh(\cosh{x})} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x}{(e^{\cosh{x}}+e^{-\cosh{x}})} =  \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x e^{\cosh{x}}}{(e^{2\cosh{x}}+1)} $

I'm not sure what to do from there.

Shall I say $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x e^{\cosh{x}}}{(e^{2\cosh{x}}+1)} = \lim_{x \to 0} 4x \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ e^{\cosh{x}}}{(e^{2\cosh{x}}+1)}  $

Comment: Is there any issue? The top approaches $0$ and the bottom approaches $\cosh(1)\ne 0$.  No calculation is needed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas right from the start I can do that?

Comment: Most limit problems you are given involve some work. This one basically does not. Our function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cosh(\cosh(x))}$ is continuous at $x=0$, indeed everywhere. So the limit is $f(0)$. Or the way I put it earlier, the top approaches $0$, the bottom approaches $\cosh(1)$, so the ratio approaches $0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much, I understand now.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be explicit, you can note that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(2x)=0\quad\text{and}\lim_{x\to 0}\cosh(\cosh(x))=\cosh(1)\ne 0,$$ and therefore our limit is $\dfrac{0}{\cosh(1)}$, which is $0$.